# how to change path which has been set for XML schema validation

Tags: notepad++, xsd-validation, xmlschema

> I've a bunch of XML failed according to XSD format set by the developers,i'm working in Notepad++ for validating the schemas provided by our organization,

I've downloaded the xml tool plugin, integrated it with notepad++, Now when i'm validating the document it should ask for a path, which I've set incorrect recently, now i want to change the path, but everytime i'm clicking validate now, it is popping no error detected.

All i want to change the path again to path provided before,so that it will work accordingly..

Please help in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I go to `Plugins > XML Tools > Validate Now` (or press `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + M`) it seems to come up every time, in my case.

Also, if I close and re-open Notepad++, the next time I go to validate an XML file, it doesn't remember what I had set last time, allowing me to specify a new XSD Schema file. This would be the easiest option to try.

You could also try going to `Plugins > Plugins Admin > Installed`, then select `XML Tools` and click `Remove`. Then close and re-open Notepad++, then add it again by going to the `Available` tab instead.

If that still doesn't work, try uninstalling and reinstalling Notepad++.